Why does the transformation of a random variable require the transformation have continuous derivative and the original pdf be continuous?
In Statistical Inference (2e, Casella & Berger), there is the following theorem (p. 51) (emphasis mine):

Theorem 2.1.5 Let $X$ have pdf $f_X(x)$ and let $Y = g(X)$, where $g$ is a monotone function. Let $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ be defined by (2.1.7). Suppose that $f_X(x)$ is continuous on $\mathcal{X}$ and that $g^{-1}(y)$ has a continuous derivative on $\mathcal{Y}$. Then the pdf of $Y$ is given by
$$
\tag{2.1.10}
f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y) \right| & y \in \mathcal{Y} \\\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Proof: From Theorem 2.1.3 we have, by the chain rule,
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
  f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) & \text{if $g$ is increasing} \\\\
-f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) & \text{if $g$ is decreasing,}
\end{cases}
$$
which can be expressed concisely as (2.1.10).

Why must $f_X(x)$ be continuous, and why must $g^{-1}$ have a continuous derivative?
If those conditions do not hold, I think $f_Y(y)$ will not be continuous, but I'm not sure why that would be a problem.

For context, here are the references from the theorem above and its proof:

(p. 50) When transformations are made, it is important to keep track of the sample spaces of the random variables; otherwise, much confusion can arise. When the transformation is from $X$ to $Y = g(X)$, it is most convenient to use
$$ \tag{2.1.7} \mathcal{X} = \{ x : f_X(x) > 0 \} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathcal{Y} = \{y: y=g(x) \text{ for some } x \in \mathcal{X} \}. $$


(p. 51) Theorem 2.1.3 Let $X$ have pdf $F_X(x)$, let $Y=g(X)$, and let $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ be defined as in (2.1.7).

If $g$ is an increasing function on $\mathcal{X}$, $F_Y(y) = F_X(g^{-1}(y))$ for $y \in \mathcal{Y}$.
If $g$ is a decreasing function on $\mathcal{X}$ and $X$ is a continuous random variable, $F_Y(y) = 1 - F_X(g^{-1}(y))$ for $y \in \mathcal{Y}$.



To formulate (2.1.10) we need $g^{-1}$ to have a derivative. No one said that it is impossible to generalize such theorems but the question is if it is worth it. Also: you could easily take a concrete example of a discontinuous $f_X(x)$ and a not continuously differentiable $g$ and figure out what the CDF and the PDF of $Y=g(X)$ are.

I realize (2.1.10) requires $g^{-1}$ to have a derivative, and that this theorem can be generalized -- in fact, a couple pages later, Theorem 2.1.8 generalizes this to $X$ that is piecewise continuous and $g^{-1}$ that has a piecewise continuous derivative. But I'm wondering why for this theorem or its proof, $g^{-1}$ must have a continuous derivative, and why $f_X$ must be continuous. Maybe I'm forgetting something basic from calculus.

That 2.1.8 exists already confirms what I wrote above. Please perform the exercise I suggested. Regarding "why" : If I was an author of a book with the title "Statistical Inference" I would leave my Bourbaki hat in the wardrobe. This is most likely what those authors have done as well.

Ok I think I see your point. If I let $g(x) = 2x$ when $x < 0$ and $g(x) = 4x$ otherwise, then there is a discontinuity in the derivative of $g^{-1}$ at 0, i.e. the derivative does not exist there, meaning $f_Y$ would not be well-defined at $y=0$. As for why $f_X$ is continuous, on p. 35 it says, "Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if $f_X(x)$ is continuous, we have the further relationship $\frac{d}{dx} F_X(x) = f_X(x)$." I suppose thus if $f_X$ is not continuous, then this relationship (and thus 2.1.10) does not hold. Thank you.

"As for why $f_X$ is continuous" in my previous comment should be "As for why $f_X$ must be continuous".

To use the variable substitution rule for integration, you need something.. for example, it is not always the case that $h'$ is integrable if $h$ is everywhere differentiable (Volterra function) (apply to $h=g^{-1}$) and the substitution law for integration needs a condition or two; it is annoying and difficult to state maximally general versions of this. Observe that $f$ being integrable would not force $f(g^{-1})$ to be integrable! However, if $f$ is continuous then this is for sure! By integrable, you can either read "Riemann integrable" or "Lebesgue measurable (and Lebesgue integrable)". So we should want $f$ continuous to expect $f_Y$, so defined, to even be a pdf. Note that a priori $\frac{d F_Y}{dy}$ does not need to be integrable...
To be fair, since the function at hand, $f_Y$, is a derivative, there are fewer concerns with the substitution rule. By the second fundamental theorem of calculus (nontrivial for Lebesgue integrals) we're all good so long as the derivative actually is integrable, or so long as $F_Y$ is absolutely continuous (really, this is what it means for $Y$ to be continuous anyway...) - but why should that be true? You want some easily checked condition to guarantee it, and "$f_X$ continuous, $g^{-1}$ $C^1$" is an easy way to achieve that. Again, I think it would be hard to be more general in an easily checkable way.
